# Initialize class with only one static method (no constructor)

Tags: cython

Say `MyClass.h` (a C++ library I am attempting to wrap) look like

```
class MyClass {
public:
  static AnotherType func();

};
```

`func()` returns some elaborate initialization of `AnotherType`, say `AnotherType(int a, int b)`

If I wrap this:

```
cdef extern from 'MyClass.h':
  cdef cppclass MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    AnotherType func();

cdef extern from 'AnotherType.h':
  cdef cppclass AnotherType:
    AnotherType(int a, int b);
```

Then how do I assign something to `func()`?

If I just do

```
cdef AnotherType another = MyType.func()
```

I just get an error message:

```
C++ class must have a nullary constructor to be stack allocated
```

(and this class does not have any constructor).

If I instead try to assign it to a pointer in a class (as per Cython's documentation on classes without nullary constructors)

```
cdef class MyClassWrapper:
  cdef AnotherType* another
    def __cinit__(self):
      self.another = MyType.func()
```

I only get the error message

```
Cannot assign type 'AnotherType' to 'AnotherType *'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your first attempt (`cdef AnotherType another = MyType.func()`) is that Cython generates code like:

```
AnotherType another{}; // no argument nullary constructor
another = MyType::func(); // copy assignment
```

Therefore `another` must be constructable without arguments. The reason it does this is so you get Python rather than C++ scoping (i.e. if `another` was assigned in an `if` statement it's accessible in the whole function, unlike in C++).

Your second way is closer to correct. However you need to make use of the copy or move constructor explicitly:

```
self.another = new AnotherType(MyType.func())
```

You probably need to tell Cython about the copy constructor for `AnotherType` (this is implicitly declared by C++ but Cython doesn't know about it by default):

```
cdef cppclass AnotherType:
    AnotherType(int a, int b);
    AnotherType(AnotherType&) # copy constructor
```

Comment: Thank you very much